# Spring advice does not work as expected

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am new in Spring AOP, and I have create an application to learn the Spring AOP, however I found that the Aspect does not work as expected, this is the core code:

Target:

```
public interface UserService {
    void getUserList();
}

@Component
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    public UserDao getUserDao() {
        return userDao;
    }

    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    public void getUserList() {
        this.userDao.getUserList();
    }
}
```

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.kk.service.impl.UserServiceImpl(..))")
    public void logTargetUserService() {
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.kk.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.getUserList(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        System.out.println("logBefore() is running!");
        System.out.println("hijacked : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        System.out.println("******");
    }
}
```

spring.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kk"/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Application:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"spring.xml"});

        UserServiceImpl userService = context.getBean(UserServiceImpl.class);
        userService.getUserList();
    }
}
```

When I run it I only got this output:

```
get user list at dao
```

It seems that the advise does not run at all.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should regist your bean as like this

```
<bean id="loggingAspect" class="your.package.LoggingAspect"/>
```

Comment: I have use this `component-scan`, then I wonder if it is necessary to register the bean in xml manually?

Comment: You are right, I have to register the bean. It works.

Comment: `@Aspect` is from Aspectj and isn't a `@Component`. So either declare it manually or add a `@Component` next to the `@AspectJ` annotation.